# Importing/Parsing JSON result from Google App Script Into JS Fiddle for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-apps-script, highcharts

I am making a bar chart visualization in Highcharts that should look like this (**please read entire post! my questions will be asked towards the end**):

[image]

I want the data to come from the following process:

**Google Spreadsheet Data -----> (Google App Script) ----> JSON FORM ----> Parsing JSON result from Google App Script in JS Fiddle to use in visualization**

The data in Google Spreadsheets looks like this:

[image]

My app for converting the google spreadsheet data into JSON form is here:

```js
function doGet(e){

 // Loading in URL
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lSOUNz26yK5BPDiE4wvvImn5tvzQ0Ony6f29tLPR9Kw/edit#gid=1370914101");

 // Loading in the Name of the Sheet
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Guestdata");

  
  
  return getUsers(sheet); 
  
}



function getUsers(sheet){
 //var jo = {};
  
  var dataArray = [];

// collecting data from 2nd Row , 1st column to last row and last column
  
  var rows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0, l= rows.length; i<l ; i++){
    var dataRow = rows[i];
    var record = {};
    record['category'] = dataRow[0];
    record['guestvalue'] = dataRow[1];
    record['daysbetweenvisits'] = dataRow[2];
    
    dataArray.push(record);
    
  }  
  
  //Use the following ONLY if you want the JSON array to have a specified user name. Otherwise, just stringify the object dataArray
  
  
  //jo.user = dataArray;
  
  //var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  
  var result = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  
}
```

The result of the program is here:

[image]

The URL of my JSON result from the app looks something like this (This specific URL I've included does not work cause I didn't include the stuff after content_key due to privacy concerns. Don't worry about this. I'm just showing you what the URL looks like):

"https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key= . . . ."

Now, I know that I could just copy and paste the JSON data into JS Fiddle and then create the highchart like this:

```js
var myJson = [{"category":1,"guestValue":0,"visits":23},{"category":2,"guestValue":96.6,"visits":45},{"category":3,"guestValue":73.2,"visits":65},{"category":4,"guestValue":60.3,"visits":85},{"category":5,"guestValue":52.5,"visits":105},{"category":6,"guestValue":46.6,"visits":125},{"category":7,"guestValue":41.4,"visits":144},{"category":8,"guestValue":37.5,"visits":163},{"category":9,"guestValue":34.4,"visits":179},{"category":10,"guestValue":31.9,"visits":199},{"category":"11-17","guestValue":25.4,"visits":258},{"category":"18-28","guestValue":17,"visits":394},{"category":"29+","guestValue":9.7,"visits":847}];

var category = [];
var guestValue = [];
var visits = [];

for (i=0; i < myJson.length; i++) {

  guestValue.push(myJson[i].guestValue);
  
  visits.push(myJson[i].visits);
  
  category.push(myJson[i].category);
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
 
  title: {
    text: null,
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: category,

    title: {
      text: 'Visits Per Customer (TTM)'
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0,     
    
    title: {
      text: 'Average Return Rate Overall: 64 Days',
      y: 10
    },
    
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
      
    }
  },
  
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f} </b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
  
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -25,
    y: 5,
    width: 280,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
   
    shadow: true
    
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Q1 / 18 (TTM) Annual Guest Value',
    data: guestValue,
    color: 'grey',
    // label color
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'grey'
       
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Days Between 1st and 2nd Visits',
    data: visits,
    color: 'green',
    // label color
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'green'
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Now here is my question.** I want the JSON data to be parsed/loaded **by the URL OF THE GOOGLE APP SCRIPT RESULT INSTEAD** so that if the google spreadsheet data is updated, the visualization will visualize the updated data when the code in JS fiddle in run. How would I do this?

Also, my URL does NOT end with 'json'. Is this an issue when I am parsing it? Would I need to convert the URL into a URL that ends with .json or something?

My attempt is below but I have no idea if I am on the right track or not. I enter in the URL but the visualization does not appear after this.

```js
var my_URL = prompt("Enter the JSON data you would like to import into Highcharts:   ");
console.log(my_URL);

$.getJSON(my_URL, function (data) {

 
 var myJson = JSON.parse(data)
  
  var myarray = [];
  
  for(var i in myJson) {
  
   myarray.push(myJson[i]);
  
  
  }
  
  var result = myarray.map(i=>([i.category, i.guestvalue, i.daysbetweenvisits]));
  
  
  var category = [];
 var guestValue = [];
 var visits = [];

for (j=0; j < result.length; j++) {

  guestValue.push(result[j].guestvalue);
  
  visits.push(result[j].daysbetweenvisits);
  
  category.push(result[j].category);
}



Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
 
  title: {
    text: null,
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: category,

    title: {
      text: 'Visits Per Customer (TTM)'
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0,     
    
    title: {
      text: 'Average Return Rate Overall: 64 Days',
      y: 10
    },
    
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
      
    }
  },
  
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f} </b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
  
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -25,
    y: 5,
    width: 280,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
   
    shadow: true
    
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Q1 / 18 (TTM) Annual Guest Value',
    data: guestValue,
    color: 'grey',
    // label color
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'grey'
       
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Days Between 1st and 2nd Visits',
    data: visits,
    color: 'green',
    // label color
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'green'
      }
    }
  }]
});


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried build-in solution for loading google spreadsheets in Highcharts? See [data.js](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module) module. For example [`data.googleSpreadsheetKey`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.googleSpreadsheetKey)

Comment: I know but I want to convert it to JSON and then bring the JSON data into JS fiddle for the chart.